# Changing java heapsizes for a websphere server using websphere and wsadminlib.py

Tags: scripting, websphere, jython, administration, wsadmin

Im trying to call a command from wsadminlib.py to change the initialHeapSize and the maximumHeapSize in a script. But unfortunately my jython (and general scripting knowledge) is still total newbie.

Im using the call

```
#Change Java Heap Size
```

setJvmProperty(nodeName,serverName,maximumHeapsize -2048 ,initialHeapSize -2048)

Which should relate to the command in the wsadminlib.py library

```
def setJvmProperty(nodename,servername,propertyname,value):

"""Set a particular JVM property for the named server
```

Some useful examples:

```
    'maximumHeapSize': 512 ,

    'initialHeapSize':512,

    'verboseModeGarbageCollection':"true",

    'genericJvmArguments':"-Xgcpolicy:gencon -Xdump:heap:events=user -Xgc:noAdaptiveTenure,tenureAge=8,stdGlobalCompactToSatisfyAllocate -Xconcurrentlevel1 -Xtgc:parallel",



"""

jvm = getServerJvm(nodename,servername)

AdminConfig.modify(jvm, [[propertyname, value]])
```

But I'm met with this issue when i run the script

WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/etc/was-scripts/administrateservertest.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "", line 14, in ?
NameError: maximumHeapsize

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I'm tearing my hair out trying to work this out

Comment: I am not sure, is it typo maximumHeapsize

Answer (score 0):

this was answered by a friend on face book

> I think you might need to make two calls, one for each property you
>   want to set. e.g.
>   setJvmProperty(nodeName,serverName,'maximumHeapsize',2048)

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a more specific answer, try this:

```
AdminConfig.modify(jvmId,[['genericJvmArguments',arguments],["maximumHeapSize", str(1536)]])
```